# 403 disallowed_useragent solution for website, android and IOS app

Tags: asp.net, xamarin

I have created an ASP.NET website by selecting a template in visual studio and got open authentication already configured, I just un commented some code and created client and app secret for google and facebook and I got authentication working fine.

Authentication is working fine for website and now I have created an Android and IOS app in Xamarin, I  an using web view but google authentication has stopped working, I am getting "403 disallowed_useragent" which is a known issue now. facebook authentication is working fine.

I have temporarily disable open authentication on my website, what are the options available now?

I am looking for a solution that works for website, responsive website on a mobile browser, Android and IOS app.

Comment: Open a Chrome CustomTab and perform the Google Auth there and capture the token on redirect

Comment: is there any article you can refer?